# implement Send for dyn Stream<Item = std::string::String>

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a nested Stream to read csv encoded data from a list of files(in a directory). The program is based on [this project](https://github.com/barter-rs/barter-rs). It reads out crypto trades and feeds them to a crypto strategy.

Example csv data looks like:

```
185075939,8289.97000000,0.00965600,80.04795032,1569888000086,False,True
185075940,8290.00000000,0.21986100,1822.64769000,1569888000086,False,True
185075941,8290.00000000,0.00187300,15.52717000,1569888000086,False,True
185075942,8290.34000000,0.00148500,12.31115490,1569888000277,True,True
```

Data files in dir looks like:

```
.rw-r--r--@ 1.0G jack  6 Feb  2021  BTCUSDT-trades-2019-10.csv
.rw-r--r--  902M jack  6 Feb  2021  BTCUSDT-trades-2019-11.csv
```

The idea is I have 2 Streams. The inner stream reads string one by one from a list of csv files inside a directory. The outer stream converts string returned by the inner stream to a crypto data structure.

The inner stream is:

```
struct MultipleFilesReader {
    data_path: String,
    data_files: Option<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>>,
    reader: Option<LinesStream<tokio::io::BufReader<tokio::fs::File>>>,

    // for filtering filename with time range
    filter_func: Box<dyn Fn(&DateTime<Utc>, &DateTime<Utc>, &str) -> bool + Send + Sync>,
    from_datetime: DateTime<Utc>,
    to_datetime: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

There is an `into_stream`, converting the struct `MultipleFilesReader` to a `futures_core::stream::Stream`:

```
    pub fn into_stream(mut self) -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
        stream! {
            loop {
                match self.readline().await {
                    Ok(line) => yield line,
                    Err(e) => match e {
                        MultipleFilesReaderError::TryAgain => continue,
                        MultipleFilesReaderError::NoFile
                        | MultipleFilesReaderError::NoMoreFiles
                        | MultipleFilesReaderError::IOError(_) => break,
                    },
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

The outer stream is:

```
struct BinanceTradeReader {
    data_path: String,

    from_date: DateTime<Utc>,
    to_date: DateTime<Utc>,

    files_reader_iter: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>>,

    convert_func: Box<dyn Fn(&BinanceTradeRecord) -> MarketEvent<DataKind> + Send + Sync>,

    _marker: PhantomPinned,
}
```

In `BinanceTradeReader`, there is a `dyn Stream<Item = String>`. The outer stream polls data from that, which is generated from the inner stream.

The following code converts it to the outer stream:

```
pub fn reader_into_stream(reader: BinanceTradeReader) -> impl Stream<Item = MarketEvent<DataKind>> {
    stream::unfold(reader, |mut reader| async move {
        loop {
            if let Some(ref mut iter) = reader.files_reader_iter {
                match iter.next().await {
                    Some(x) => match csv_line::from_str::<BinanceTradeRecord>(&x) {
                        Ok(e) => {
                            if reader.filter_data(&e) {
                                let res = (*reader.convert_func)(&e);

                                break Some((res, reader));
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        // TODO: parse failure, log error
                        Err(_) => continue,
                    },
                    None => break None,
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is the compiler asks me to implement `Send` for the inner stream:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn Stream<Item = std::string::String> + 'static)`
```

From the outer stream's definition, the inner stream is already pinned, `files_reader_iter: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>>,`. I am not sure what this means, because `Send` is already implemented for Pin. In rust I can not implement `Send` for a struct, as far as I know.

How do I fix this? Maybe there is a simpler way to implement a nested stream?
The example is inside a forked project, I put it [here](https://github.com/naijim/quant-test).
My nested stream is [here](https://github.com/naijim/quant-test/blob/main/examples/engine_with_dir_trades.rs).

**Updated below**

Here is an example showing what I am trying to do, which reduces some complexity of the original one:

```
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use futures_core::stream::Stream;
use futures_util::pin_mut;
use std::pin::Pin;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let a = A { inner: None };
    let b = B {};
    a.inner = Some(b.into_stream()).map(|i| -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>> { Box::pin(i) });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let s = A::into_stream(a);
        pin_mut!(s);

        while let Some(t) = s.next().await {
            println!("{:?}", t);
        }
    });
}

struct A {
    pub inner: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn into_stream(mut a: A) -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
        stream::unfold(a, |mut a| async move {
            loop {
                if let Some(ref mut iter) = a.inner {
                    match iter.next().await {
                        Some(x) => {
                            break Some((x, a));
                        }
                        None => break None,
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct B {}

impl B {
    pub fn into_stream(mut self) -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
        stream! {
            let mut a = vec!["1".to_string(),"2".to_string()].into_iter();
            loop {
                match a.next() {
                    Some(x) => yield x,
                    None => break,
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Put the above into an editor, still having the `Send` requirement:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn Stream<Item = String> + 'static)`
```